# Can something be logically necessary now but not in the future?

Tags: modal-logic, time

Can something be logically necessary now but not in the future? I probably always assumed it couldn't, that it followed from the laws of logic alone, and that these are immutable etc..

I don't think necessity in general is limited to one tense only. Temporal logicians ask if the past is necessary and the future contingent (not necessary). But do they include logical necessity in that, and if so what are some examples of logical necessity that isn't always the case?

Comment: A possible example would be, "The time is now," which seems true whenever it is uttered (since it is "now" when it is uttered), but which on another level seems to change in truth-value. This is still a temporal example, but an example from temporal logic, and such as satisfies some of the topic-neutral/permutation-invariant parameters for "pure logicality." Perhaps a more promising case would be the theory of [contingently abstract objects](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4320719).

Comment: I would have thought that either it does not change (it is always now) or it is not logically necessary @KristianBerry

Comment: It seems like a possible counterexample to, "Logical truths are absolutely unchanging." Granted, the relation under which it would count as changing would be as a sentence-token: the sentence-type is always true (or is beyond truth, being more like a variable by itself), but each sentence-token becomes in some sense false as time passes. I mean, I'm not really sure about all that; but so again, it just seems like it *might* be an example of what you're asking about.

Comment: OTOH, if you mean to ask whether the law of noncontradiction, or of the excluded middle, or those kinds of things, can change, the answer might be that the logical laws that could never change would be those used to define the concept of "change" itself, and if we could pry apart some logical laws from that definitional process, we would find changeable laws.

Comment: Necessity is not contingency, but even more: it is the opposite.

Comment: i sort of get what you mean. the time was now but that time is now 5 minutes ago @KristianBerry but i am a little unconvinced that "the time is now" says anything besides the fact that now is now (which is always the case). what are you referring to with "the time" unless "now"? a length of time? idk if these are necessarily now, not if they are events, anyway

Comment: Necessity *in general* is not limited to timeless issues, but *logical* necessity, on its *standard* understanding, is. There are very few standard logical necessities, Boolean tautologies and valid predicate formulas, and they are surely timeless. Everything else isn't necessary *logically*, including the past. It can be physically or metaphysically necessary, but not logically (unless "the past" is defined to make its immutability tautological). Of course, you can relativize the notion to some non-standard logic, but then the answer depends on which logic you choose for the exercise.

Comment: what do you mean "which logic you choose"? what sort of tautologies are timeless @Conifold ?

Comment: [Tautology (logic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)). You can set up a system of possible worlds with explicitly time-dependent logic, mathematics, accessibility relations, etc. Then, of course, you can have logical (or some other) necessity evolve with time, but this is typically not done for logic.

Comment: what do you mean "explicitly time-dependent logic"? are some bachelors married at some time @Conifold ?

Comment: Today LEM is valid but tomorrow is not, etc. What happens to bachelors is not about logic, scopes of concepts can evolve without any changes to it.

Comment: hmm i dunno what you are actually getting at with these cryptic remarks @Conifold are you saying that what is a tautology is eternal or not?

Answer (score 3):

As far as necessity goes, forms of necessity are essentially defined with reference to *all possible* examples of some kind. A temporal necessity is true for all possible times; a physical necessity is true for all possible physical dynamics (or: for types of causation, a physical necessity is true of all possible tokens per type); a logical necessity is true for all possible logical systems—and so when logic is self-applied while standing both above and within all other kinds of systems, we end up with a picture of logical necessity as the most absolute necessity there could be.

Now, one might deny that there is such a necessity in the first place, although if this were so, then it would seem to be necessary that nothing was necessary: for if it were logically possible for something to be logically necessary, then in the end it would seem as though the mere possibility of something's absolute necessity would mean the actual necessity of that thing. As Kant put it: to say that something is necessary is to say [that it is actual just by being possible](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page%3ACritique_of_Pure_Reason_1855_Meiklejohn_tr.djvu/110); or in [contemporary modal logic, "possibly necessary" collapses to "necessary."](https://www.philosophyetc.net/2005/03/possibly-necessary.html)

However, one famous thinker who sought to imagine that eternal truths could be contingent was [Descartes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-modal/#EteTru):

> Another reason that Descartes’ view is difficult to conceive is that Descartes takes eternal truths to be necessary. That is, it is difficult to conceive how eternal truths could be necessary if they were created by a free act of God. Descartes is clear that the eternal truths are necessary: he says that “the necessity of these truths does not surpass our knowledge” (“To Mersenne, 6 May 1630,” AT 1:150, CSMK 25). If eternal truths are necessary, however, it should not be the case that they could have been otherwise. Yet Descartes’ commitment to divine omnipotence appears to commit him to this view...

So it is that some analysts *don't* accept that iterated modalities always collapse to whichever directly prefixes the modified terms. With respect to Descartes' viewpoint, they say:

> An alternative view (developed and defended by Edwin Curley) is that Descartes holds that eternal truths are necessary, but that they are not necessarily so. On this reading, Descartes’ view involves iterated modalities: a number of truths are possibly necessary, but God chooses only some of these possibilities to be the actual necessary truths.

For a broader, recent discourse on iterated modalities, see [Gregory[11]](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/p/pod/dod-idx/iterated-modalities-meaning-and-a-priori-knowledge.pdf?c=phimp;idno=3521354.0011.003;format=pdf).

Comment: “Possibly Necessary” only collapses to necessity in S5, Kristian. If accessibility is just a preorder like in S4, and not a symmetric, reflexive and transitive relation like S5, then in one accessible world w1 a proposition p might be true and necessary, and w2 also accessible has p false, such that w2 is not accessible to w1.

Comment: idt i understood how your answer answers the question

Comment: While a fairly reasonable proposal that “logical necessity” should behave like S5, I’m not sure it’s absolutely obviously true. Consider - what if some mathematical objects exist in some possible worlds but not others, that have scope on the limiting behaviour of logical inferences?

Comment: @doot_s for the most part, my answer is, "No: if something is necessary, it is unchanging, especially if it's logically necessary."

Comment: @PaulRoss as far as I know, S5 is the most widely accepted system nowadays, but at any rate, since I went on to discuss no-collapse iteration theories, I didn't mean to declare that the collapse thesis is certainly true (I myself don't even believe that the possibility and necessity operators are the "real" basic ones, here).

Comment: @doot_s I should say: if "necessarily" means "not possibly not" (which is one of the standard textbook definitions nowadays), then asking if logical necessities can change means asking if there are things that both can, and can't, change. So either one goes to dialethism, separates possibility into levels, or other drastic/strange things; **or** one takes logical necessity to be unchanging. *However*, we can still ask a similar question, which is whether all logical *actualities* are unchanging; the claim that all pure logic is ultimate says, "No," but must that claim be made?

Comment: Fair enough! It’s certainly an easier semantics to work with, but in metaphysics there seems to be a bit of push-back. Essentialism seems to be coming back into vogue in order to get around its limitations, which just seems daft to me.

Comment: @PaulRoss I wish I had a better grasp of essentialism, or at least robust versions of it. It sounds like an interesting option, but it's hard for me to view existential modality as extrinsic/relational, and the word "essence" carries a lot of intrinsic/non-relational connotations as far as I see its use. So I must be missing something!

Comment: Argh, I meant "it's hard for me to view existential modality as **not** extrinsic/relational."

Answer (score 0):

"This sentence exists" may be a tautology, but it hasn't always existed. So perhaps not all tautologies are always the case.

Comment: I'm not sure, "This sentence exists," counts as a tautology (admittedly, the concept of something being a tautology is not obviously absolute, though).

Comment: I guess that depends on whether you are a realist or not. Meaning whether sentences exist before someone has formulated them. Discovery vs. creation.